# -[__NSArrayI addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, realm

I have this code:

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    var array: AnyObject = []
    for obj in Category.allObjects() {
        if var add = obj as? Category {
            array.addObject(add.name)
            println(add.name)
        }
    }

    return String(array[section] as String)
}
```

Im using a Realm database and I am trying to get one of the columns of the database to print in the section headers. Im also using a the same process for all the other required UITableView methods eg/ numberOfSectionsInTable etc etc. The code is giving me this error:

```
    2014-10-26 20:47:33.479 Project[14631:937721] -[__NSArrayI addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdaf270ddb0
2014-10-26 20:47:33.481 Project[14631:937721] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdaf270ddb0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109960f35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001095f9bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010996804d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001098c027c ___forwarding___ + 988
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001098bfe18 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   BuildersUtility                     0x0000000108d7f720 _TFC15BuildersUtility29ProductsDetailsViewController27numberOfSectionsInTableViewfS0_FCSo11UITableViewSi + 1408
    6   BuildersUtility                     0x0000000108d7f8ca _TToFC15BuildersUtility29ProductsDetailsViewController27numberOfSectionsInTableViewfS0_FCSo11UITableViewSi + 58
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010a478a7e -[UITableViewRowData _updateNumSections] + 84
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010a479474 -[UITableViewRowData invalidateAllSections] + 69
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010a2cdb03 -[UITableView _updateRowData] + 214
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010a2e300f -[UITableView numberOfSections] + 27
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010a4e0645 -[UITableViewController viewWillAppear:] + 97
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010a327821 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 487
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010a352960 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 776
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010a353487 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 523
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010a353f47 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 43
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010a499509 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 202
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010a277973 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 521
    18  QuartzCore                          0x000000010a089de8 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 150
    19  QuartzCore                          0x000000010a07ea0e _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
    20  QuartzCore                          0x000000010a07e87e _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    21  QuartzCore                          0x0000000109fec63e _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 242
    22  QuartzCore                          0x0000000109fed74a _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 390
    23  QuartzCore                          0x0000000109feddb5 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 89
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109895dc7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109895d20 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010988bb53 __CFRunLoopRun + 1123
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010988b486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    28  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010dec79f0 GSEventRunModal + 161
    29  UIKit                               0x000000010a1fe420 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    30  BuildersUtility                     0x0000000108d9589e top_level_code + 78
    31  BuildersUtility                     0x0000000108d958da main + 42
    32  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010baaf145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

BTW if you have a better way for me to extract the code from the database for a project like this please chirp in! :)

Thanks in Advance

Comment: "I" stands for **I**mmutable. You are trying to append to an immutable array, which doesn't work (for obvious reasons).

Comment: Oh ok thanks. so how come normal Arrays in swift aren't mutable? and also how do I change this? Cheers

Comment: Also, this code is inefficient because it builds the array for each section in your table, extracts a single string and then throws the array away. You should build the array in another method, such as the method that fetches your data and store it in a property

Comment: ok, so would it be something like a function that extracts the data once and it call it within all the sections? @Paulw11

Comment: Yes, you can create the array once and store it in a property - then just refer to it

Comment: I have answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893043/iphone-crash-using-addobject-on-a-nsmutablearray/31871614#31871614
 I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`allObjects` will return you an instance of `RLMResults`, which is one of the two list types in Realms, the other being `RLMArray`. They are both made to be similar to NSArrays or swift arrays, and implement a protocol called `RLMCollection`. Among other things, that means you can access its elements with normal `[i]` notation. So you can simply write

```
return Category.allObjects()[section].name
```

although you might want to do some checking before you return. Also, it is generally not advisable to repeat the `allObjects()` query more than you need to, so you could cache in a lazy instance variable or similar. In this case there probably aren't that many categories/section headers, so it shouldn't be an issue.

More importantly, keep in mind that although the `RLMResults` list you get back *is* ordered in the sense that it is an ordered list, there is no inherent order among the `Category` instances in the `Realm`, so the next time you do `Category.allObjects()` you are not really guaranteed to receive the objects in the same order. So what you should do is really to create an `RLMArray` of `Category` objects and make that a property of another object. Then the order will be preserved.

Answer (score 2):

It is because `AnyObject` does not support the method `addObject`

I think what you have in mind is that you want the variable `array` to be an array of type `AnyObject`.

You should declare it this way:

```
var array:[AnyObject] = []
```

And then when you want to add anything to the array, do this:

```
array.append(add.name)
```

Comment: Wow thanks So much! @AnthonyKong What was I actually declaring then, just as a side questions?

Comment: var array: AnyObject means that you declare the variable 'array' as being of type* AnyObject, which could be any object class. Next you initialise it to [], which apparently makes it an NSArray, which you can discover with a breakpoint. The reason you can write array.addObject is that you just told the compiler that array is an AnyObject, so it could potentially respond to any selector. *AnyObject is actually a protocol, but that is just a detail.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what @AnthonyKong is pointing out, it is a bit unclear from the above code why you would want an array of AnyObject in the first place.

```
var array = [AnyObject]()
```

It seems what you actually want is an array of `String`?

```
var array = [String]()
```

then your return statement is simplified down to:

```
return array[section]
```

When feeling up to it you might also look into `filter` to rip out some of that almost-boiler-plate-logic in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem but with an NSMutableArray.  Thanks to @Gusutafu's comment above that setting an array to @[] converts it to an NSArray.

My incorrect code (selectedTags is an NSMutableArray):

```
selectedTags = ([theInputParameters valueForKey:kAcronymTagsSelectedTags] != nil)
? [theInputParameters valueForKey:kAcronymTagsSelectedTags]
: @[];
```

This gave the error -[__NSArrayI addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance when I tried to add an object.

My corrected code

```
selectedTags = ([theInputParameters valueForKey:kAcronymTagsSelectedTags] != nil)
? [theInputParameters valueForKey:kAcronymTagsSelectedTags]
: [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[]];
```